Excel(VBA) Formula in added column needing logical workaround
I have a table similar to the one below, apart from its about 600 rows long:

and I am trying to find an excel formula or even with VBA since in reality there are a lot of rows, to give me a resulting column as follows:

To elaborate, I would like a list of all the knots in the levels prior where the Level is 4. So to explicitly explain the last result we get 18, because that is the knot on that row, the next level 3 is where the knot is 14, then the level 2 is 12, and now comes the tricky bit..Since the level 4 and 3 have already been dedicated, we ignore all 4s, 3s, and 2s above, and consider the level 1 and 0, hence 4 and 2 to obtain the final result 18,14,12,4, and 2.
Is it possible, maybe by adding additional columns or with a VBA solution to achieve the result column?
I tried a formula in the reult column  like tih: =IF(C9=4; CONCATENATE(“,", TRUE, B9:INDEX(B$1:B9; MAX(IF(C$1:C9=0; ROW(C$1:C9), IF(C$1:C9=1; ROW(C$1:C9); 0))))), ’”), which didn't work...
I couldn't get past that...
Thanks in advance.
By the way, I have Microsoft Excel 2021.

I am afraid I am not able to understand the logic of allocation/"dedication"... How should " level 4 and 3 have already been dedicated" be understood? All levels have been "dedicated" for the first case (on the fifth row), if "dedication" means to preliminarily used them. If the second case (16,14,12,4,2) may have a meaning, what about the third one which you try explaining? Wouldn't all nodes been dedicated? What if some other rows have to be processed?

well, the algorithm is to start from the line going upwards, so if a level has been dedicated, that means it already has a  level entry.

What does "Dedicated" mean? Please, read my above comment and try explaining each issue I put in discussion. I can design a code able to return what you show there, but I cannot what to do if you insert other 5 rows and play with levels and knots. Can you add these rows, or more and fill them according to the logic you have? I will maybe deduce it looking to the output...

Thanks guys, but I got the answer myself. I can't believe how easy it was in the end:
TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,
    IF(B3=4, A3, ""),
    IF(B3=4, MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$18=3)*($A$2:$A$18<A3), $A$2:$A$18)), ""),
    IF(B3=4, MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$18=2)*($A$2:$A$18<A3), $A$2:$A$18)), ""),
    IF(B3=4, MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$18=1)*($A$2:$A$18<A3), $A$2:$A$18)), ""),
IF(B3=4, MAX(IF(($B$2:$B$18=0)*($A$2:$A$18<A3), $A$2:$A$18)), "")
)


When using a table you can use this formula:
=IF([@Level]=4,
    LET(dataKnots,TAKE([Knots],ROW()-1),
    dataLevels,TAKE([Level],ROW()-1),
    d,REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(5,1,4,-1),
            LAMBDA(r,l,HSTACK(r,TAKE(FILTER(dataKnots,dataLevels=l),-1)))),
    TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,d)),
"")

It checks the data above (and including) the current row.
Within the REDUCEpart each previous level is filtered and stacked to the result.


what is "dataknots"??

When using a LET-formula you can assign a variable (dataKnots) a value --> TAKE([Knots],ROW()-1): this returns the range from then Knots-column from the first to the current row (row where the formula resides). Afterwards, 'dataKnots' can be used in the rest of the formula.

=MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=4,ARRAYTOTEXT(XLOOKUP({4,3,2,1,0},B2:b,A2:a,,,-1)),"")))
It - if current row in column B is 4 - looks back for last 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 from current row and up and returns the corresponding value in column A. Wrapped in a join function (ARRAYTOTEXT)
You could replace ARRAYTOTEXT with TEXTJOIN in case you don't want spaces in between values:
=MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=4,TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP({4,3,2,1,0},B2:b,A2:a,,,-1)),"")))
Or turn it into a table and use: =IF([@Level]=4,TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP({4,3,2,1,0},INDEX([Level],1):[@Level],INDEX([Knots],1):[@Knots],,,-1)),"")

I'Ve been tring to make it work and realised that I have Excel 2021, and not Microsoft 365. Is there a solution existing for Excel 2021? Thanks in advance. I'll also add it at the top sorry for that.

Added a table solution that should work in Excel 2021

With listing level as parameter, otherwise similar logic to others. Using Microsoft 365 (for LET, LAMBDA etc.):
=LET(
    row_num, ROW() - ROW(Table1[#Headers]),
    list_level, 4,
    list_levels, SEQUENCE(list_level + 1, , list_level, -1),
    IF(
        [@Level] = list_level,
        ARRAYTOTEXT(
            XLOOKUP(
                list_levels,
                TAKE([Level], row_num),
                TAKE([Knots], row_num),
                ,
                0,
                -1
            )
        ),
        ""
    )
)


As range
=LET(
    last_row, COUNTA(A:A),
    knots, A2:INDEX(A:A, last_row),
    level, B2:INDEX(B:B, last_row),
    list_level, 4,
    list_levels, SEQUENCE(list_level + 1, , list_level, -1),
    list_knots, LAMBDA(level_, row_num,
        IF(
            level_ = list_level,
            ARRAYTOTEXT(
                XLOOKUP(
                    list_levels,
                    TAKE(level, row_num),
                    TAKE(knots, row_num),
                    ,
                    0,
                    -1
                )
            ),
            ""
        )
    ),
    MAP(level, SEQUENCE(ROWS(knots)), list_knots)
)



For Excel 2021
Replace TAKE with INDEX:
=LET(
    row_num, ROW() - ROW(Table2021[#Headers]),
    list_level, 4,
    list_levels, SEQUENCE(list_level + 1, , list_level, -1),
    IF(
        [@Level] = list_level,
        ARRAYTOTEXT(
            XLOOKUP(
                list_levels,
                INDEX([Level], 1, 1):INDEX([Level], row_num, 1),
                INDEX([Knots], 1, 1):INDEX([Knots], row_num, 1),
                ,
                0,
                -1
            )
        ),
        ""
    )
)


Is there also a solution for Excel 2021?

@KingsleyObeng, when you get a chance please test the updated section.

ok, now I get an overflow error. I'm trying to disect the formula to find out why

May I ask whether you're using table or range? I would take a look at the data causing the error - please add it to the question if possible.
